# Install python requirements to existing venv by pip in ansible

Tags: python, pip, ansible, python-venv

I have existing venv before run my ansible task (nephelaiio.pyenv)

I want just install requirements in my existing venv.

Here is code from my ansible role:

```
- name: Install project interpreter libraries
  pip:
    executable: "/home/int/.pyenv/versions/int-3.7.3/bin/pip"
    requirements: "/home/int/int/requirements.txt"

The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/tmp/ansible_pip_payload_38mr2d/__main__.py", line 254, in <module>
   from pkg_resources import Requirement
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
fatal: [my.host.com]: FAILED! => {
   "changed": false,
   "invocation": {
       "module_args": {
           "chdir": null,
           "editable": false,
           "executable": "/home/int/.pyenv/versions/int-3.7.3/bin/pip",
           "extra_args": null,
           "name": null,
           "requirements": "/home/int/int/requirements.txt",
           "state": "present",
           "umask": null,
           "use_mirrors": true,
           "version": null,
           "virtualenv": null,
           "virtualenv_command": "virtualenv",
           "virtualenv_python": null,
           "virtualenv_site_packages": false
       }
   },
   "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (setuptools) on debian's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location"
}
```

-

```
int@my.host.com:~$ ls -al /home/int/int/requirements.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 int int 110 Aug 28 09:59 /home/int/int/requirements.txt
int@my.host.com:~$ ls -al /home/int/.pyenv/versions/int-3.7.3/bin/pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 int int 259 Aug 28 10:41 /home/int/.pyenv/versions/int-3.7.3/bin/pip
int@my.host.com:~$ whereis pip
pip: /home/int/.pyenv/shims/pip /home/int/.pyenv/shims/pip3.7
```

requirements.txt has data

pip by path is works

ansible 2.8, debian 10

Update: seems like "sudo apt install python-pip" fix it.

Is it right decision?

Update2: My problem - 
I missed the requirements block for pip ansible module.

Answer (score 3):

> "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (**setuptools**) on debian's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location"

Reading the requirements from the module documentation [pip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html#pip-manages-python-library-dependencies)

> The below requirements are needed on the host that executes this module.

- pip
- virtualenv
- setuptools

To solve the problem install *`setuptools`* in the remote hosts (that executes this module). For example in Ubuntu

```
$ dpkg -l '*setuptools*'
ii  python-setuptools           39.0.1-2
ii  python3-setuptools          39.0.1-2
```

, or FreeBSD

```
$ pkg info | grep setuptools
py27-setuptools-40.8.0         Python packages installer
py36-setuptools-40.8.0         Python packages installer
```

Comment: I missed the requirements block for pip ansible module. Thanks for help =)